# Creation of JSON Array with data from database

Tags: java, json, jdbc, data-structures

I have values for a particular field in my database rel_act stored as 1234,5678,9112
I read these values through a map array 'rslt' so when I read them as

I wish to create a json object in the particular format

`"rel_act": [{"ref":"1234"},{"ref":"5678"},{"ref":"9112"}]`

Please advise

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a simple wrapper to your JDBC code:
(Note that the SQL2JSON.convertDateToString() method has not been included in this example, delete it or add your own)

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
/**
 * Creates a JSONARRAY from an java.sql.ResultSet.
 * @author Aries
 *
 */
public class SQL2JSON 
{

    public static JSONArray convert(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, JSONException
          {
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while(rs.next()) {
                  int numColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

                  for(int i=1; i<numColumns+1; i++) {

                    String column_name = rsmd.getColumnLabel(i);  //Bugfix , works better than getColumnName() /Aries 

                    switch( rsmd.getColumnType( i ) ) {
                      case java.sql.Types.ARRAY:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getArray(column_name));     break;
                      case java.sql.Types.BIGINT:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
                      case java.sql.Types.BOOLEAN:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getBoolean(column_name));   break;
                      case java.sql.Types.BLOB:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getBlob(column_name));      break;
                      case java.sql.Types.DOUBLE:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getDouble(column_name));    break;
                      case java.sql.Types.FLOAT:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getFloat(column_name));     break;
                      case java.sql.Types.INTEGER:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
                      case java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getNString(column_name));   break;
                      case java.sql.Types.VARCHAR:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getString(column_name));    break;
                      case java.sql.Types.TINYINT:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
                      case java.sql.Types.SMALLINT:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getInt(column_name));       break;
                      case java.sql.Types.DATE:
                        obj.put(column_name, SQL2JSON.convertDateToString(rs.getDate(column_name)));      break;
                      case java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP:
                        obj.put(column_name, SQL2JSON.convertDateToString(rs.getTimestamp(column_name))); break;
                      default:
                        obj.put(column_name, rs.getObject(column_name));    break;
                    }
                  }

                  json.put(obj);
                }

            return json;
          }
}
```

Here is an example how it is called.
I am using a custom MySQL transactionpool and JDBC SQL handle object, 
but it should be modifiable to any JDBC driver object (MySQL, Sybase, H2, HSQLDB, Oracle, ...)

```
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public synchronized JSONObject getCustomerReferences(int custID) {

            DBTransaction trans=null;
            TransactionPool transactionPool = null;
            JSONArray myArrayOfRefs= new JSONArray();
            JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();


        try {
            transactionPool = TransactionPool.get();
            trans = transactionPool.beginWork();

            Map<String, Object> optionalParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            optionalParams.put("customerId", custID);


             String selectQuery ="SELECT orderId AS ref FROM table1 WHERE custId='[customerId]';" //with 'AS' you can customize your output to any JSON name
             JSONArray myArrayOfRefs = null;
             ResultSet rs = mySQLTransactionHandle.query(selectQuery, optionalParams);
             if(rs.next()) {
                 myArrayOfRefs =  SQL2JSON.convert(rs);
                 }

             //add JSON array to a JSON object 
             myObject.put("rel_act", myArrayOfRefs); //Add null check.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //Add logging
       }
        finally
        {
             try {
                    transactionPool.commit(mySQLTransactionHandle);
                } catch (SQLException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace(); //Add logging
                }
        }
            return myObject;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In a recent project I used Google gson, you can create a custom serializer in order to create the format you want from an object.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization

Example:

```
    GsonBuilder gb = new GsonBuilder();
    gb.registerTypeAdapter(YourClass.class, new CustomSerializer());
    Gson gson = gb.create();
    JsonElement json = gson.toJsonTree(yourObjectInstance);
```

And for the CustomSerializer:

```
public class CustomSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Object> {
    public JsonElement serialize(Object object, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonObject jo = new JsonObject();
        //create your custom json here
        return jo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First advice: Do not hand-write your JSON serialization code. Use a well-proven library such as [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). This library allows you to generate a JSON string from a dictionary, object, or array with a single line of code.

On a side note you may want to make your code and JSON more readable. For example, if your only values per array item are the numbers from your example, you don't need key-value pairs. You can simplify your JSON to `"rel_act": [ "1234", "5678", "9112" ]`. Furthermore instead of `rel_act` you can use a more readable name following the camelCase convention - the advantage is that your Java object from which you serialize the JSON will have a typical Java Name, and also any JavaScript deserializing the JSON will get a name that follows typical JavaScript naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray("\"rel_act\": [ \"1234\", \"5678\", \"9112\" ]");
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your SQL dialect, but by now, a lot of RDBMS support standard SQL/JSON or vendor specific variant. E.g. in standard SQL (e.g. Oracle), you can extract your JSON like this:

#### Oracle, standard SQL

```sql
SELECT json_object(
  KEY 'rel_act' VALUE json_arrayagg(
    json_object(KEY 'ref' VALUE t.ref)
  )
)
FROM t
```

#### Postgres

```sql
select 
  json_build_object('rel_act', json_agg(json_build_object('ref', t.ref)))
from t
```

#### Third party option

Since you're using Java, you might also be able to use jOOQ for this job, either as a tool to [export your JDBC `ResultSet` as JSON](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-json/):

```java
try (ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery()) {
    System.out.println(ctx.fetch(rs).formatJson(format);
}
```

Or using its [SQL/JSON capabilities](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/json-functions/) as shown above. Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.